# Loop for deleting first line of Multiple Files using Bash Script

Tags: bash

Just new to Bash scripting and programming in general. I would like to automate the deletion of the first line of multiple .data files in a directory. My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.data ;
do tail -n +2 $f | echo "processing $f";
done
```

I get the echo message but when I cat the file nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not changing the file itself. By using `tail` you simply read the file and print parts of it to `stdout` (the terminal), you have to redirect that output to a temporary file and then overwrite the original file with the temporary one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.data; do
    tail -n +2 "$f" > "${f}".tmp && mv "${f}".tmp "$f"
    echo "Processing $f"
done
```

Moreover it's not clear what you'd like to achieve with the `echo` command. Why do you use a pipe (`|`) there?

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) will give you an easier way to achieve this. See devnull's answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and with a very helpful explanation. The reasoning behind my code was that I wanted to  delete the line with `tail` then get a notification that it had done that by echoing it to the terminal... to see where I was at in terms of it completing the 1000+ files. Thanks for your comments on using `tail`, I'll be sure to use it properly in future.

Answer (score 23):

> I get the echo message but when I cat the file nothing has changed.

Because simply `tail`ing  wouldn't change the file.

You could use `sed` to modify the files in-place with the first line excluded.  Saying

```
sed -i '1d' *.data
```

would delete the first line from all `.data` files.

---

EDIT: BSD `sed` (on OSX) would expect an argument to `-i`, so you can either specify an extension to backup older files, or to edit the files in-place, say:

```
sed -i '' '1d' *.data
```

Comment: Cheers

I tried this (in a test directory with copied files) and I got the following output:

**sed: 1: "201001010000a.WAH.data": command a expects \ followed by text**

Comment: @Marko It seems that you didn't execute the correct command.  Since you've already copied the files to a new directory, you can simply copy/paste the command mentioned above.

Comment: Still no luck, could it be a problem with `sed` on OSX?

Comment: @Marko The mentioned command should work with BSD `sed` (the one that's available on OSX).  What does `sed -i '1d' filename` do (where `filename` refers to a single file)?

Comment: @Marko It turns out that `sed` on OSX (i.e. BSD `sed`) expects an extension as an argument to `-i`.  You can say `sed -i '' '1d' *.data`.  Also edited the answer.

Comment: @devnull this only remove the first line from 1 file in the dir, not all the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
for f in *.data; do
  echo "processing $f"
  tail -n +2 "$f" | sponge "$f"
done
```

If you don't have `sponge` you can get it in the `moreutils` package.

The quotes around the filename are important--they will make it work with filenames containing spaces.  And the `env` thing at the top is so that people can set which Bash interpreter they want to use via their PATH, in case someone has a non-default one.  The `set -eu` makes Bash exit if an error occurs, which is usually safer.

Answer (score 0):

`ed` is the standard editor:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.data; do
    echo "Processing file \`$f'"
    ed -s -- "$f" < <( printf '%s\n' "1d" "wq" )
done
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` is here just because you should always use this when using globs, especially in a script: it will make globs expand to nothing if there are no matches; you don't want to run commands with uncontrolled arguments.

Next, we loop on all your files, and use `ed` with the commands:

- `1`: go to first line
- `d`: delete that line
- `wq`: write and quit

Options for `ed`:

- `-s`: tells `ed` to shut up! we don't want `ed` to print its junk on our screen.
- `--`: end of options: this will make your script much more robust, in case a file name starts with a hypen: in this case, the hyphen will confuse `ed` trying to process it as an option. With `--`, `ed` knows that there are no more options after that and will happily process any files, even those starting with a hyphen.